# The Space of Cellular Maps

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, gn.general-topology, cw-complexes, mapping-space

Let $X$ and $Y$ be CW complexes.

Inside of the space of maps $\mathrm{map}(X,Y)$, we have the subspace $\mathrm{CW}(X,Y)$, consisting of just the cellular maps from $X$ to $Y$.  The Cellular Approximation Theorem tells us that the inclusion $\mathrm{CW}(X,Y)\to \mathrm{map}(X,Y)$ induces an isomorphism on $\pi_0$ (in both the pointed and unpointed contexts).

My question:  is the inclusion a weak equivalence?  (Feel free to use any reasonable topology.)

EDIT:  The answer is NO.  I'm leaving this here since some interesting ideas are percolating in the comments.

Comment: Let X be a point.  (Note that cellular approximation only gives you a surjection on $\pi_0$ - you need to use cellular homotopies $X \times I \to Y$ as well to get the correct answer.)

Comment: You're right.  Oops.

Comment: I suppose the simplicial set whose $n$-simplices are the *cellular* maps $X\times \Delta^n\to Y$ models the homotopy type of $\mathrm{map}(X,Y)$.

Comment: > Charles Rezk
Does it true for the infinity-dimensional X?

Comment: @Nikita.  I would think so.  It should be enough to prove that $\mathrm{Cell}(X_m,Y)\to \mathrm{Cell}(X_{m-1},Y)$ is a Kan fibration, where $X_m$ is the $m$-skeleton of $X$, and $\mathrm{Cell}$ is the simplicial set of maps I defined, and that looks like it follows from cellular approximation.